# InvalidReferenceException while using struts2 doubleselect tag

Tags: java, jsp, select, struts2

I need to show two dropdown for Class-Section.

**Description:**

first select is appearing but second select is not showing the value in the dropdown.

My double select looks like:

```
<s:doubleselect label="Standard"  
    name="standard" 
    listValue="standard"  
    list="#session.standardList"
    doubleList="#session.standardList.section" 
    doubleName="section" 
    doubleListValue="section"></s:doubleselect>
```

Standard class looks like:

```
public class Standard {
    String standard;
    ArrayList<String> section;
        // getters and setters below
   }
```

**Exception:**

```
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression parameters.formName is undefined on line 150, column 43 in template/simple/doubleselect.ftl.
    at freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:125)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.getStringValue(Expression.java:118)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause of the issue, As the exception says `formName` was not found, i encapsulated double-select tag inside the form tag and all start working fine.

Now form tag looks like:

```
<s:form name="studentsubmit" action="add/submitstudent">
    <s:doubleselect label="Standard" name="standard" listValue="standard"
        listKey="standard" list="#session.standardList" doubleList="section"
        doubleName="section" ></s:doubleselect>
</s:form>
```